# El "ranking" de reputación no funciona correctamente cuando los usuarios tienen la misma reputación

Tags: bug

Buen día,

Hoy por pura casualidad encontré que tengo la misma reputación que otro usuario, sin embargo mi nombre tiene un puesto mayor al otro usuario (Supongo que lo ordena alfabéticamente) pero esto es incorrecto, en este caso el puesto de los dos o más usuarios debería ser el mismo

Es decir, tanto Legna como yo deberíamos tener el puesto `90` y Juan debería conservar el puesto `92` ya que no hay puesto `91` por haber un empate en el puesto `90`.

[image: Reputación]

Comment: Esto hay que reportarlo en meta general, pero me suena a que es así por defecto. La "posicionalidad" es una visión caprichosa que para algunos casos se usa como vos decís, y para otros no.

Comment: Donde puedo ver el rankig?

Comment: @Jred0n29 al acceder a tu perfil, en la sección de Resumen, entre tu reputación y el gráfico hay un enlace (o debería). Te redirige a [User Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/year/es-stackoverflow/).

Comment: como estas seguro de que tu argumento es el criterio a seguir en el posicionamiento del ranking? o simplemente estas asumiendo que funciona de esa manera? cuando se manejan ranking no pueden haber huecos numericos aunque existan empates debe haber otro criterio estadistico a seguir...